# Type overriding for parametrized method in scala

Tags: generics, scala, overriding, covariance

I try to override my parametrized method in scala,

I have an abstract class like this :

```
abstract class Ranking[G <: AbstractGenome, MG <: MultiGoalLike] {
  def operate(individuals :IndexedSeq [IndividualMG[G,MG]]):IndexedSeq [IndividualMG[G,MG]
}
```

I want two type of ranking which need decorated version of `IndividualMG` : `IndividualMG[G,MG] with IDistance`, and `IndividualMG[G,MG] with IRank`.

My `IndividualMG` class signature :

```
class IndividualMG[G <: AbstractGenome,MG <: MultiGoalLike] (val genome: G,val multiGoal:MG)
```

My two class for ranking :

```
class Ranking1 [G <: AbstractGenome, MG <: MultiGoalLike] extends Ranking[G,MG] {
override def operate(individuals :IndexedSeq [IndividualMG [G,MG] with IRanking])
:IndexedSeq [IndividualMG [G,MG] with IRanking]= {
return ...
}

class Ranking2 [G <: AbstractGenome, MG <: MultiGoalLike] extends Ranking[G,MG] {
override def operate(individuals :IndexedSeq [IndividualMG [G,MG] with IDistance])
:IndexedSeq [IndividualMG [G,MG] with IDistance] = {
return ...
}
```

I have an error, it's logic because type differs when i try to override, but how can i make to verify inheritance type  `[I <: IndividualMG [G,MG]]`  for my two ranking operator in class `Ranking1` and `Ranking2` ?

Thanks stack,
SR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
abstract class Ranking[
    -I <: IndividualMG[G, MG], 
    G <: AbstractGenome, 
    MG <: MultiGoalLike] {
  def operate(individuals :IndexedSeq[I])
}

class Ranking1[
   G <: AbstractGenome, 
   MG <: MultiGoalLike] 
  extends Ranking[IndividualMG[G,MG] with IDistance, G, MG] ...
```

Comment: Thanks, i have little problem with the minus of I, because i want to return IndexedSeq[Individual[G,MG] with ...] for operate();I delete the covariant minus, and it's ok :)

Comment: Indeed my fault I have not looked carefully enough, I thougt it was only an argument.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a *Path dependent type*.

```
abstract class AbstractGenome
class ConcreteGenome extends AbstractGenome
class MultiGoalLike
trait IRanking

abstract class Ranking[G <: AbstractGenome, MG <: MultiGoalLike] {
  type RankType <: IndividualMG[G,MG]
  def operate(individuals :IndexedSeq [RankType])
}

class IndividualMG[G <: AbstractGenome,MG <: MultiGoalLike] (val genome: G,
                                                          val multiGoal:MG)

class Ranking1 [G <: AbstractGenome, MG <: MultiGoalLike] extends Ranking[G,MG] {
  type RankType = IndividualMG [G,MG] with IRanking
  override def operate(individuals :IndexedSeq [RankType])= println("it worked!")
}

val cg = new ConcreteGenome
val mgl = new MultiGoalLike

val r1 = new Ranking1[ConcreteGenome, MultiGoalLike]

val i1 = new IndividualMG(cg, mgl)
val i2 = new IndividualMG(cg, mgl) with IRanking

r1.operate(Vector(i1)) // error
r1.operate(Vector(i2)) // OK
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks ! I love this second approach, it's more flexible for my future use case. I give the valid answer to @didierd because it's the first, but, thanks for your help too !